# Allow only access to camera device in HTML5

Tags: ios, html, input, camera

I'm currently developing application using the camera for iphone in HTML5 with

```
<input type="file" accept="capture=camera">
```

The problem is that I have a little list that give me the choose between my library and my camera.

[image]

My idea is to have two buttons, one for the library and an other for the camera.

I know the way to only give the library but not for the camera.

**Question:** Is there a way to separate the two types?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunaly not possible :/

Extract from [HTML Media Capture - Security and privacy considerations](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/#security) :

> In addition, the User Agent implementation is advised to provide an
>   indication to the user when an input device is enabled and make it
>   possible for the user to terminate such capture. Similarly, the User
>   Agent is advised to offer user control, such as to allow the user to:
>
> - select the exact media capture device to be used if there exist
>     multiple devices of the same type (e.g. a front-facing camera in
>     addition to a primary camera).
> - disable sound capture when in the
>     video capture mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I didn't come across a solution, I only found unofficial sources stating that this is not possible. All you can do is require either `video/*` or `image/*` via the `accept` attribute.

Comment: Well, this is really strange. Why not giving the opportunity to the developer to use only the camera. I know about the attribute, thanks again for remind me. Too bad for us :/

Comment: In most cases, somebody at Apple has been thinking through this and decided to not allow this. Maybe because a user could be annoyed if he/she cannot chose from the library after he/she just took a picture to be uploaded on the website using the native camera app. Also there isn't really a need to prevent the use of the library, is there?

Comment: Well, I wanted to do only one step to capture a picture and not press one button and an other one to take a picture so, for the moment, it's not really important but I guess I made my point to skip one step :)

Thanks you again for the informations :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in iOS6 through 10. It does work on Android 3.0+.

The `capture` attribute, introduced by [HTML Media Capture](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/), should force iOS to jump straight to the cam app but it's not supported.

From [the spec](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/):

> The capture attribute is a boolean attribute that, if specified, indicates that the capture of media directly from the device's environment ... is preferred.

PS: Your code is slightly incorrect, you should use
`<input accept="video/*,image/*" capture >` to:

1. capture both video and photos
2. jump directly to cam (when supported)

See [Correct HTML Media Capture Syntax](https://blog .addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) for more details.

Answer (score -4):

Write the following takePhoto acton method:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender { 
     UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     picker.delegate = self;
     picker.allowsEditing = YES;
     picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
     [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Finally, we do the same for the selectPhoto action method, but changing the sourceType to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary.

```
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(UIButton *)sender {  
     UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
     picker.delegate = self;
     picker.allowsEditing = YES;
     picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
     [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Implementing the Delegate Methods of UIImagePickerController

When the user takes a photo with the camera and resizes the image (photo resizing is allowed since we said allowsEditing = YES when we created the image picker). It is a NSDictionary which contains, among other things, the original image and the edited image (accessible through the tag UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage).

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
     self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: we are talking about HTML5, so this answer is not correct