# HTML Media capture - Prevent user to import from library

Tags: android, html, ios, file-upload, image-uploading

I am working with HTML Media Capture APIs:

```
<form action="server.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

and I was wondering if it's possible to prevent the user to select an existing image/picture from the device (i.e. mobile) and restrict them to take a new picture/screenshot using the camera only (no existing images)

Does anyone know?

Thank you

Comment: thanks you are right

Comment: `<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture>` but works only on Android, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40498166/813988)

Comment: @OctavianNaicu thank you